# Java generic collections and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

Basically I need to have an abstract class, that contains a field of a list that details it can hold subclasses of a certain class, and then create a concrete class that stores a specific subclass of that certain class.

Better explained in code I am sure:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public abstract class AbsClass {
    protected List<? extends A> list;
}

public class ConClass extends AbsClass {
    list = new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

With the above code i get the compiler error

> The method add(capture#3-of ? extends A) in the type List < capture#3-of ? extends A> is not applicable for the arguments (B)

the line where the list is instantiated.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Regarding your compile error: you're leaving out details.  This error has to do with trying to invoke the method `list.add`, not with your assignment.  Your code won't compile for other reasons; namely the assignment occurs outside of a constructor or initializer block.

Comment: works fine for me...  as it should...

Comment: @mlaw no, it doesn't. Nowhere is <A> declared! We're left to guess where it is declared.

Comment: @glow: `A` is a class, not a type parameter.  A bit misleading since it's one character but it's a common fake class name, and it's included in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just type `AbsClass`?

```
public abstract class AbsClass<T extends A> {
    protected List<T> list;
}

public class ConClass extends AbsClass<B> {
    list = new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

Of course at that point it's not necessary to even move the instantiation to the subclass:

```
public abstract class AbsClass<T extends A> {
    protected List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public class ConClass extends AbsClass<B> {
    //... other stuff ...
}
```